# HTML drag and drop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a html form element which enables users to put four things in their order. For example I want to ask a user what their favorite animal is and to put that in order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    updateOrder(ev.target.id);

}

function updateOrder(id) {
  var w = document.getElementById(id);
  for (var i = 0; i < w.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var node = w.childNodes[i];
     document.getElementById('order-'+i).value=node.id;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="order">Put in order:</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="order-1" id="order-0" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="order-2" id="order-1" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="order-3" id="order-2" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="order-4" id="order-3" value="">
<div style="border: 1px dashed #ddd; padding: 0.5em; min-height: 2em; margin-bottom: 4px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-from" placeholder="Pak hier de opties">
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-1" class="label label-default">Optie 1</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-2" class="label label-default">Optie 2</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-3" class="label label-default">Optie 3</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-4" class="label label-default">Optie 4</div>
</div>
<div class="form-control" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-form" placeholder="sleep ze in de juiste volgorde hier naartoe"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now is my issue that when I want to rearrange dropped elements, especially when you drop for example #option-1 on #option 2, I have unsuspected output. In stead of moving #option-1 after #option-2, it places #option-1 in #option-2 and the hidden input fields get strange values. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dropOrder(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (ev.target === document.getElementById('drop-from') || ev.target === document.getElementById('drop-to')) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  else {
    ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), ev.target.nextSibling)  
  }
  updateOrder();
}

function updateOrder() {
  var w = document.getElementById('drop-to');
  var children = w.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var node = children[i];
    document.getElementById('order-'+i).value=node.id;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="order">Put in order:</label>
      <input type="text" name="order-1" id="order-0" value="">
      <input type="text" name="order-2" id="order-1" value="">
      <input type="text" name="order-3" id="order-2" value="">
      <input type="text" name="order-4" id="order-3" value="">
<div style="border: 1px dashed #ddd; padding: 0.5em; min-height: 2em; margin-bottom: 4px;" ondrop="dropOrder(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-from" placeholder="Pak hier de opties">
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-1" class="label label-default">Optie 1</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-2" class="label label-default">Optie 2</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-3" class="label label-default">Optie 3</div>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-4" class="label label-default">Optie 4</div>
</div>
<div class="form-control" ondrop="dropOrder(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-to" placeholder="sleep ze in de juiste volgorde hier naartoe"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your code. Please review it.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

var dropFrom = document.getElementById('drop-from');
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (ev.target === dropFrom) {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  else {
    ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), ev.target.nextSibling)  
  }
  updateOrder(ev.target.id);
}

function updateOrder(id) {
  var w = document.getElementById('drop-from');
  var children = w.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var node = children[i];
    document.getElementById('order-'+i).value=node.id;
  }
}
```

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="order">Choose your favorite animals and put it in order:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="order-1" id="order-0" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="order-2" id="order-1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="order-3" id="order-2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="order-4" id="order-3" value="">
    <div style="border: 1px dashed #ddd; padding: 0.5em; min-height: 2em; margin-bottom: 4px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-from" placeholder="Pak hier de opties">
      <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-1" class="label label-default">Horse</div>
      <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-2" class="label label-default">Dog</div>
      <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-3" class="label label-default">Cat</div>
      <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="float: left;" id="option-4" class="label label-default">Cow</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="drop-form" placeholder="sleep ze in de juiste volgorde hier naartoe"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There was something wrong in splitting the code. Now it is the whole code at once. It should work.

Comment: Dropping elements from #drop-from on #drop-form works great. Dropping elements from #drop-from on _elements in_ #drop-form does not work. How can I make it that elements are only dropped on the div and not on the elements in the div?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want that in any case, the drag element will dropped to the container element (`#drop-from`). I was updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks to your code I was able to fix the code. I changed drop-form to drop-to s.t. it is less confusing. Then in my answer, you can see the code working as I expected. Thanks a lot @Mosh Feu!